# iptables presale me to ssh access or calling methods remotely

Tags: server, ssh, iptables

I have a linux openwrt unit at its start I can not make a ssh access if I do iptables -F.

If I iptables -L -n -v, I find several rules that are automatically inserted and it prevents me from doing the same ssh access and calling methods remotely using web services such as device listening on port 8080.

The problem though that if I write it myself of the rules in the filter table and if I do on every boot iptables -F to access my camera and call the remote methods then all will be deleted from the filter table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the iptables rules are loaded up by using `iptables-restore` on a specific file in `/etc`.  So if you can figure out what that file is named, you can manually invoke `iptables-save` and write out your good rules to that file.  Then on next boot it will use your modified rules instead of what used to be in there.

I'm guessing the location is `/etc/iptables.rules`, but to find yours `grep -R iptables-restore /etc/init.d/`.

Once you know that file, you can modify your live rule set and then save a good set with the following command as root:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

Or, as a normal user via sudo:

```
iptables-save | sudo tee -a /etc/iptables.rules
```

You may even want to save off the current rules to a file, edit the file by hand, and then reload from this file.  For example:

```
sudo iptables-save > edited-rules
vim edited-rules #or whatever editor, gedit?
sudo iptables-resore < edited-rules
```

However you do it, be sure that when you are done, you save the new ruleset to whatever the file is in etc (again, probably `/etc/iptables.rules`)